# How to sort Windows Spooler correctly? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, print-spooler

I got 4 different folders with 20 .txt files in each. Documents in folder 1 are named 1,2,..,20; in folder 2 01,02,..,20; in folder 3 001,002,..,020; in folder 4 0001,0002,..,0020. Now I want to print these files. I've changed the registry so you can right click and press print (usually not possible with more then 15 files). After I clicked on print it goes into the spooler before its going to print. Now the problem is that the order is always messed up, I think its sorted by sent date or something. But I want to sort it by name so it prints from page 1 to page 20 or even more. Now its like 1,5,6,8,2...

I already know that you could just click on sort by name but everytime you open the spooler again it gets messed up. Its also for another company I am working for and they dont wanna open the spooler everytime. If it was for me it would do so.

I hope you guys understand my problem. I think the text is hard to understand but maybe somebody will :D

Comment: forgot to say that these 4 folders are just for testing because I thought that different names would change the order